# get value from asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I found many subject about but I can't get a solution, I'm doing a soap request in doInBackground method of asyncTask, and I want to get an Integer to know if the process is done, here I call my asyncTask:

```
            Simulation.AsyncSoapCall task = new Simulation.AsyncSoapCall();
            try {
                Integer taskResult = task.execute().get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My AsyncTask class:

```
private class AsyncSoapCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {


    Integer result;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    Boolean isUrlAvailable = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    AsyncSoapCall(){
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {

            String namespace = getResources().getString(R.string.NAMESPACE);
            String url = getResources().getString(R.string.URL);
            String soapaction = getResources().getString(R.string.SOAP_ACTION);
            String login = getResources().getString(R.string.login);
            String mdp = getResources().getString(R.string.mdp);

            isUrlAvailable = cd.isUrlAvailable();

            // check for Internet status
            if (isUrlAvailable) {

                String idApplication = Installation.id(getActivity());

                SOAPContact soapContact = new SOAPContact(namespace, url, soapaction, login, mdp);

                soapContact.saveParams(getResources().getString(R.string.origine), db);

                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 2;
            }
        } else {
            result = 3;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }
}
```

I don't get error my app crasha at this line:
                    Integer taskResult = task.execute().get();

Answer (score 0):

try to get the value from onPostExecute like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
int yourNum = result;
}
```

that's it

Comment: Ok but I think I have an exception with execute.get();

Comment: you just execute the async Task like
      new AsyncSoapCall .execute();

Comment: And how to get the int in my main class which calling the asyntask ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the doc?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

AsyncTask has no "get" method.
You need to define a OnPostExecute method which will be called when your task is over with your Integer as a parameter.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private Integer myInteger;
    private void blabla(){
        Simulation.AsyncSoapCall task = new Simulation.AsyncSoapCall() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                //... Your code here ...
                   MyActivity.this.myInteger = result;
                   MyActivity.this.myMethod(result);   
            }
        }
        try {
            task.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void myMethod(Integer integer){
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the value in my main class which is calling the AsyncTask

Comment: I completed my exemple. You can set a property or call a method from the onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method with the help of interfaces,

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AsyncSoapCall request = new AsyncSoapCall(new AsyncSoapCall.AsyncSoapInterface() {
            @Override
            public void callBack(String callBackValue) {

                Log.d(TAG,callBackValue);

            }
        });
        request.execute();


    }
}
```

**AsyncSoapCall.java**

```
public class AsyncSoapCall extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


    interface AsyncSoapInterface{


        void callBack(String callBackValue);
    }

    AsyncSoapInterface callbackObj;

    AsyncSoapCall(AsyncSoapInterface callbackObj)
    {
        callbackObj = callbackObj;


    }




    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        callbackObj.callBack("Your value");

    }
}
```